# Цикл for...in - после метода return не осуществляется выход из функции

Tags: javascript, циклы, for

Цикл for...in - после метода return не осуществляется выход из функции и цикл начинается ещё один раз!

```
function remove_Phone() {

    for (let key in phoneBook) {

        let arr = String(phoneBook[key]).split(", ");

        let removeIndex = arr.indexOf(contactName);

        if (removeIndex >= 0)
        {
            arr.splice(removeIndex, 1);

            phoneBook[key] = arr.join();

            return true;
        }

    }

    return false;

}
```

То есть, возвращает true, но не выходит из функции, возвращается к строке for...in, а затем к строке return false, после чего выходит из функции, возвращая, соответственно, false!

Comment: Это вы по отладчику так решили? Метод один раз возвращает 1 значение. Другого быть не может.

Comment: Если он возвращает `true` значит он выходит из функции. Покажите где и как вы её вызываете.

Comment: Да, по отладчику - WebStorm, но, как сейчас понял, сам ошибался - для наглядности вместо return писал alert... Но тем не менее, при обоих вариантах эта функция возвращала false в вызвавшую её функцию... Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
function remove_Phone() {

    let result = false;
    for (let key in phoneBook) {

        let arr = String(phoneBook[key]).split(", ");

        let removeIndex = arr.indexOf(contactName);

        if (removeIndex >= 0)
        {
            arr.splice(removeIndex, 1);

            phoneBook[key] = arr.join();

            result = true;
            break;
        }

    }

    return result;

}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Получилось!

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста

Comment: @AzizUmarov а в чем смысл? У ТС код точно так же работает.